# Class 'SendEmail' not found while doing Amazon SQS queue

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-sqs

I followed [this official guide](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues) in order to implement Amazon SQS mailing system into my Laravel 5 project

I've done executing both essential commands from the doc:

```
php artisan queue:table
php artisan make:command SendEmail --queued
```

The second line has created the file app/Commands/SendEmail.php for me as expected, which contains:

```
<?php namespace App\Commands;

use App\Commands\Command;

use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeQueued;

class SendEmail extends Command implements SelfHandling, ShouldBeQueued {

    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the command.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

Now, I try to run simple Laravel queue command:

```
Queue::push(new SendEmail($message));
```

Then, I got this error message:

```
FatalErrorException in CandidateController.php line 47:
Class 'SendEmail' not found
```

I really have no clue. I tried including "App/Commands" into my "classmap" of composer.json but still no luck

This is my Controller method that triggers error:

```
public function get_testemail()
    {
        Queue::push(new SendEmail( array(       // <<< This is Line 47
            'can_id' => 105,
            'template'=>'candidate_register'
            )));
        var_dump($result);
        die();
    }
```

Really, really appreciate your helps!

Thank you in advance, sir /|\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm, i just fixed this by adding

```
use App\Commands\SendEmail;
```

To the top of the file...